# How to produce the table flip emoticon (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻?

Tags: symbols, typography, fun

Oh man, I don't even know where to put this... or how to begin. As a joke, I'm trying to get the ascii art of the guy flipping a table in a question on an exam. I've tried verbatim but it won't display the characters.

I know it might be a long shot, but does anyone have an idea how to get this little guy

```
(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻
```

to display? I know I should provide a MWE, but... yeah, I don't even have that.

Thanks!

Comment: Just save it as an image; or (Xe|Lua)TeX.

Comment: What is that? Remember that students don't typically appreciate jokes in their exam papers. For one thing, you need to be very, very sure they will all know immediately that it is a joke. Were I among your students, I would not realise that was meant to be a joke and I would not be pleased at your adding to my anxiety and time pressure while I tried to puzzle it out.

Comment: I was trying to convey that if they forget the +C on an indefinite integral, I would flip a table. Sorry if the humor was lost on you cfr.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Uhm, this is Unicode we're talking about here.

Comment: @cfr I appreciated jokes in my exams.  They reduce anxiety.

Comment: @endolith The trouble is ensuring that everyone realises immediately that it *is* a joke.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This may require some tweaking, but most of the symbols can be found in the `stix` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stix}

\newcommand{\kora}{$($\rotatebox{45}{$\smile$}$^{\circ}\smwhtsquare^{\circ})\rotatebox{45}{$\smile$}\mkern-6mu\frown$\raisebox{0.5ex}{$\bot$}$\mkern-3.5mu-\mkern-3.5mu$\raisebox{0.5ex}{$\bot$}}

\begin{document}
\kora
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Edit:

Here's a version using standard shapes. Thanks to A Feldman for the hint on the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,amsmath}

\newcommand{\kora}{%
(\raisebox{0.5em}{\rotatebox{-45}{)}}$^{\circ}{\scriptscriptstyle\Box}^{\circ}$)\raisebox{0.5em}{\rotatebox{-45}{)}}\rotatebox{90}{)}\raisebox{0.2em}{\LARGE \_\hskip-.1em\textvisiblespace\hskip-.1em\_}
}
\begin{document}
\kora
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While I applaud your effort and awesomeness, I have been trying to install this font (no idea what I'm doing) and it's sort of ridiculous!

Comment: @Jon I added another version that doesn't use the `stix` package.

Comment: Holy crap I love you!

Answer (score 16):

Okay, here is a try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\begin{document}

({\ttfamily J}$^{\circ}$$\square$$^{\circ}$){\ttfamily J}$\frown$\LARGE{\_\hskip-.04in\textvisiblespace\hskip-.04in\_}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

This works for me on Windows:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\newfontfamily{\fliptablefont}{SimSun}
\newfontfamily{\fliptablefont}{Arial Unicode MS}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\fliptable}{{\fliptablefont(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻}}
\begin{document}
\fliptable
\end{document}
```