# How to include a Lenny face in a LaTeX document? e.g. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Tags: unicode, fun

How would one include a "classic" Lenny face in a LaTeX document?

A paper is due tomorrow and I am curious. e.g. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

I have attempted to use the `verbatim` environment but it has proved fruitless.

Comment: related: [Silly typesetting question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306177/silly-typesetting-question)

Comment: I attempted following the techniques described, as was looking for a close to "automatic" solution. @wilx 's  comment seemed to be the only one fitting that bill, but the results were... [less than optimal](http://i.imgur.com/uLDb3TF.png)

Comment: I'm very curious of the context in which you need to use the face. Can you share with us the related text in the paper?

Comment: As an aside, I'll be especially be happy if someone could use LaTeX/TeX  to make a "Jenny face"!!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you use a Unicode aware TeX dialect like XeLaTeX it is just to paste the text and make sure the chosen font contains the characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}
  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
\end{document}
```

[image: ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)]

Answer (score 146):

Staightforward with a stack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,trimclip,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\savestack\eye{\rotatebox{90}{$^\circ\mkern-6mu\raisebox{1pt}{)}$}}
\savestack\nose{\raisebox{3pt}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\clipbox{0pt 1pt 0pt 0pt}{?}}}}
\savestack\mouth{\rotatebox{90}{(}}
\scaleleftright{(}{\stackanchor[2pt]{\eye \nose \eye}{\mouth}}{)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From there to a macro follows directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,trimclip,scalerel}
\savestack\eye{\rotatebox{90}{$^\circ\mkern-6mu\raisebox{1pt}{)}$}}
\savestack\nose{\raisebox{3pt}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\clipbox{0pt 1pt 0pt 0pt}{?}}}}
\savestack\mouth{\rotatebox{90}{(}}
\newcommand\Lenny{\scaleleftright{(}{\stackanchor[2pt]{\eye \nose \eye}{\mouth}}{)}}
\begin{document}
This is my Lenny face: \Lenny
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a variant that won't distort line spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,trimclip,scalerel}
\savestack\eye{\rotatebox{90}{$^\circ\mkern-6mu\raisebox{1pt}{)}$}}
\savestack\nose{\raisebox{3pt}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\clipbox{0pt 1pt 0pt 0pt}{?}}}}
\savestack\mouth{\rotatebox{90}{(}}
\newcommand\Lenny{(\scalerel{\stackanchor[2pt]{\eye \nose \eye}{\mouth}}{)}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2] \Lenny{} \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Finally, a more proportioned variation, that can present Lenny from different font families (by way of optional argument):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,trimclip,scalerel}
\newcommand\Lenny[1][]{\bgroup#1%
  \savestack\eye{\rotatebox{90}{\footnotesize$^\circ\mkern-6mu\raisebox{1pt}{)}$}}%
  \savestack\nose{\raisebox{4pt}{\scalebox{1}[-1.3]{\clipbox{0pt 1.5pt 0pt 0pt}{?}}}}%
  \savestack\mouth{\rotatebox{90}{(}}%
  (\kern-1pt\scalerel{\stackanchor[1.0pt]{$\eye\nose\!\eye$}{\mouth}}{\kern-1pt)}%
  \egroup%
}
\begin{document}
{\tiny rmfamily sffamily mirrored-ttfamily}\par
\Lenny\quad
\Lenny[\sffamily]\quad
\scalebox{-1}[1]{\Lenny[\ttfamily]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @KolaB.  I actually received the Populist badge yesterday for this answer, because as of then, the criteria were satisfied.  I will find out today if it is taken away, with additional voting or not.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes [Badges, once earned, cannot be unearned.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) See also: [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/is-it-possible-to-lose-badges)

Comment: That's great answer as well, isn't it? Congratulations :)

Comment: @Au101 Thanks so much.  My first gold answer.

Comment: The top "face" has the most potential from what I see here among all answers, to make into a "Jenny face"!

Comment: @amWhy Is it any coincidence that I have two daughters named "Jenny"?  Jennifer and Jenia.

Answer (score 24):

With some help from [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/), I got this first approximation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    $\overset\frown{\smash(^\circ} \underset\smile{\ \text\textinvglotstop} \overset\frown{\ ^\circ} )$
\end{document}
```

[image: ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)]

Answer (score 13):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa,relsize,amsmath,graphicx}
\def\Lenny{\raisebox{-.8ex}{\resizebox{2.5em}{1.2em}{%
${\overset{\left(^{\overset{\frown}{\circ}}\!\! %
{_{{\overset{{\text{\scriptsize\textinvglotstop}}}{\mathlarger\smile}}}}\!\!\!%
^{\overset{\frown}{\circ}}\!\right)}{}}$}}}
\begin{document}
I am Lenny \Lenny
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code (based on an example by David Griffiths):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\len{{\mbox{$\resizebox{.31in}{.08in}{\includegraphics{len}}$}}}
\begin{document}

    Here's a sample:
    $\resizebox{.31in}{.08in}{\includegraphics{len}}$

    Can I put it into a line of type?  $\resizebox{.43in}{.11in}{\includegraphics{len}}$
    How about using the macro: \len

    \begin{equation}
        1 + \len = 0
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: lenny text]
here is the image I used: [image: len]

Comment: So Lenny changes 0 to $\infty$? :)

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your font's hinting...