# I need a TeX-donkey

Tags: graphics, fun

In my town there will be next weekend an exhibition with 7000 donkey images. It is related to a sculpture group with 7 donkeys called "donkey's way" which will be installed in the summer.

I would like to add one (or perhaps more) TeX-donkey images.

If you would like to participate and create one: you are completely free to choose the look and implementation. Additional ducks and lions are allowed.

I will choose the one I like best (I will take votes into account), print it out, add your name(s) and put it in one of the boxes which collects the images.

If you need inspiration: There is a Facebook group "7000Esel", which shows some already existing images. The official logo of the project looks like this:

[image]

I will also add a bounty to this question as soon as possible -- which means after Paulo's bounty has be awarded. (But I regret that I can't split the bounty among all this beautiful donkeys (and ducks in disguise)).

## Update

I made prints from all the answers (if the authors would get a pdf: drop me a mail) and brought them to the exhibition. I will try to make fotos on sunday and post them.

## Update

I went to the exhibition. There were thousands of donkey images side-by-side in a number of corridors.

[image]

Among these various tex donkeys (I couldn't put all in the boxes as there was a time limit).

[image]
[image] 
[image]
[image]

There was also an image of another disguised duck:

[image]

I'm very satisfied and thank everyone for their contributions ;-)

[image]

Comment: Must this be TeX (Tikz) or is a svg or pdf also allowed?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: As I'm asking this on tex.sx and I'm asking for a TeX-donkey, there should be some TeX in it, but external resources are allowed. As I wrote you are quite free regarding the implementation. You can e.g. draw a donkey on paper and scan it.  Only don't violate rights of other people by using some random image from the net. I don't want to get sued ;-)

Comment: Should this be CW?

Comment: @JosephWright Sure if you think it would be better. Can I still add a bounty to a CW? After all I promised ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, no, that wouldn't work: I'll leave alone

Comment: @JosephWright bounties still work for CW questions and answers. Search for "How does Community Wiki mode affect bounties" in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work.

Comment: There must be a fun pun image on DonK(nuth) that someone (not me) can draw.

Comment: @EthanBolker Something like [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312312/)? I only just saw your comment having posted ;). Though I went with Don{Knuth} rather than DonK(nuth). Not sure where you'd find a picture of an ey.

Comment: Bounties for everybody!

Comment: @PauloCereda: But I wanted to add a bounty ;-(. What happens if I add a bounty too? Can we split them? (The justification for the bounty is naturally wrong. I got some very neat donkeys -- which were very well received.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: oh the bounty text is indeed misleading. `:)` I can award my bounty in 24 hours, then you can add one too!

Comment: Are you asking authors to send you PDFs or offering to send authors PDFs?

Comment: @cfr I'm offering to send the pdf

Comment: ooh I saw another duck disguised as donkey. `:)`

Comment: Can't believe you submitted my pun. Now I will have to email you for the PDFs!

Comment: Where's your own submission?

Answer (score 153):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek,amssymb,amsmath,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{2cm}
\Huge\obeylines\parskip-.7em
\resizebox{1.8em}{1.5em}{$\;\;\Uplambda\!,\!\!,\!\!,\!\!,\!\!\Uplambda$}
$\,\;_{\odot} {}_{\odot}$
{\small$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\backslash\;\;\;\;\;\;\backslash$}
\vskip.5em
$\;\; ^{{(}\overset{{_\delta\;\;\;\,_\wr}}{}\!)}$
\vskip-.5em
\resizebox{2.2em}{.4em}{$\;\;\;\;\smile$}
\end{minipage}
\vbox{\noindent\TeX\\ for\\ donkeys\\(and  ducks)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat ;) What does the delta represent? The rest I can kind of see.

Comment: Supposedly is the right  [nostril](https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8423/7733247032_e5dd6843af_c.jpg) ... I now, surely there are better symbols for this (may be a rotated "sigma or simply a circle  ...)  but I was too sleepy for a  fine tuning. `:(`

Comment: Oh. I thought that was meant to be the donkey's body...

Comment: I wonder what they'll make of this if it gets into one of the boxes!

Comment: @cfr Smell is you are a TUG member

Answer (score 143):

Taking up TeX's infamous tradition of logotypes, here's an asinine adaptation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\def\fontsss#1#2#3{\fontsize{#3\unitlength}{0pt}%
                   \usefont{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(50,20)
  \put(0,14){\rotatebox{145}{\fontsss{bx}{sl}{16}E}}
  \put(12,15){\rotatebox{-105}{\fontsss{bx}{sl}{9}S}}
  \put(17,12){\rotatebox{-100}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\fontsss{sbc}{sl}{30}E}}}
  \put(39,0){\rotatebox{30}{\fontsss{m}{n}{14}L}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Esel]

[A German donkey is an Esel]

Comment: Neat idea. Will have to try how it changes its character with various fonts  ;-)

Comment: Do donkeys usually have antlers? ;)

Comment: only the three-legged ones!

Comment: Don’t be silly — it’s not three-legged, it’s a six-legged donkey in silhouette.

Comment: @Robert : ... that's not a "leg" ...

Comment: Such an original idea. I love it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Many thanks for the bounty, although I'm already embarrassed enough that this should now be my most valued answer... ;-)

Comment: I like the idea very much (but the other are good too so if was a difficult choice) I'm also embarassed that it is my most valued question -- I even got a gold badge from it. Btw: On the print out I added the comments of cfr, yours and Peter ... I found them very to the point ;-) If you want to have it, drop me a mail.

Comment: Congrats for the bounty.

Answer (score 111):

Here is my TikZ proposition (from [donkey-silhouette](http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/140000/nahled/donkey-silhouette-1445006716Ws8.jpg)).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,svg.path}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[scale=-.3pt]
    \draw[line width=1pt,fill=gray!90!white,drop shadow]
    svg "M 202,594 c -31,-3 -7,-35 1,-47 -14,-27 33,-48 6,-72 -9,-20
    9,-43 -11,-61 -6,-13 -8,-35 -17,-12 -8,20 11,44 -10,63 5,20 10,45
    -5,63 7,26 -26,39 -48,27 -20,-21 22,-36 16,-59 10,-16 28,-33 11,-52
    13,-28 -12,-50 -12,-78 3,-26 -10,-53 -1,-79 4,-20 6,-47 -22,-41
    -23,12 -45,33 -74,31 -23,3 -45,-20 -28,-40 0,-16 -2,-33 2,-49 14,-21
    46,-3 63,-21 0,-10 1,-18 -0,-25 7,-1 20,-17 20,-21 -17,-8 -0,-24
    -15,-38 -9,-23 -26,-45 -29,-71 21,-7 42,28 55,46 6,9 10,22 18,30
    18,0 5,-35 15,-49 0,-13 17,-50 25,-20 8,26 6,54 4,82 -4,11 11,20
    18,29 7,10 14,21 18,33 2,15 11,30 9,45 15,15 -15,29 9,39 19,20 52,7
    67,-11 29,-32 92,-18 103,24 15,42 -0,86 -10,127 5,14 5,30 -1,45 7,19
    14,41 2,60 -2,10 17,27 -7,30 -17,7 -58,-0 -38,-25 15,-17 5,-40
    24,-57 1,-15 -9,-50 -14,-49 -4,-8 -14,-32 -20,-30 -16,12 6,34 -12,48
    -4,20 7,45 -11,63 13,27 -37,33 -46,13 8,-19 21,-34 27,-55 15,-10
    20,-57 -6,-35 -18,2 -32,2 -33,24 -13,22 15,46 -4,67 4,23 21,49 5,73
    -11,10 19,28 -7,34 -11,5 -24,6 -36,3 z M 112,152 c 0,-18 -14,9 0,0
    z";
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The same code with better indentation:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,svg.path}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[scale=-.3pt]
    \draw[line width=1pt,fill=gray!90!white,drop shadow] svg "M
%
     202,594c -31,-3     -7,-35 1,-47   -14,-27 33,-48    6,-72
    -9,-20 9,-43       -11,-61          -6,-13 -8,-35    -17,-12
    -8,20               11,44           -10,63            5,20
     10,45             -5,63             7,26            -26,39
    -48,27             -20,-21           22,-36           16,-59
     10,-16 28,-33     11,-52 13,-28    -12,-50 -12,-78   3,-26
    -10,-53 -1,-79        4,-20 6,-47   -22,-41          -23,12
    -45,33                      -74,31  -23,3            -45,-20
    -28,-40                      0,-16  -2,-33            2,-49
     14,-21 46,-3        63,-21 0,-10    1,-18 -0,-25     7,-1 20,-17
     20,-21-17,-8     -0,-24 -15,-38    -9,-23 -26,-45   -29,-71 21,-7
%
     42,28 55,46       6,9 10,22          18,30       18,0 5,-35 15,-49
     0,-13 17,-50    25,-20  8,26         6,54        4,82 -4,11 11,20
            18,29   7,10      14,21       18,33       2,15
           11,30   9,45       15,15      -15,29       9,39
          19,20    52,7       67,-11      29,-32      92,-18
         103,24    15,42     -0,86       -10,127      5,14 5,30
       -1,45       7,19       14,41       2,60       -2,10 17,27-7,30
      -17,7       -58,-0     -38,-25      15,-17      5,-40       24,-57
      1,-15       -9,-50     -14,-49     -4,-8       -14,-32      -20,-30
    -16,12         6,34      -12,48      -4,20        7,45        -11,63
    13,27         -37,33     -46,13       8,-19       21,-34       27,-55
    15,-10         20,-57   -6,-35       -18,2       -32,2        -33,24
   -13,22 15,46    -4,67     4,23         21,49       5,73 -11,10 19,28
   -7,34 -11,5      -24,6-36,3zM          112,152     c0,-18 -14,9 0,0
%
    z";
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A fine and proud donkey!

Comment: Perfect for `pin the tail on the donkey`.

Comment: Just saw the indentation ;-))))

Answer (score 109):

Here are three varieties of an alternative rendering of a donkey based on an [openclipart image by Timothy King](https://openclipart.org/detail/211/shiny-key). But note that Inkscape exported useless code so the correspondence with the original is poor in all three cases.

## Variant 1 (Original)

[image: don-key 1]

## Variant 2 (Shiny)

[image: don-key 2]

## Variant 3 (Power of Knuth)

[image: don-key 3]

## Variant 1 (Original)

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{cabin}
\begin{document}
% basic key based on Inkscape export from Timothy King's key at https://openclipart.org/detail/211/shiny-key
  \begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.8pt, x=0.8pt, decoration={text effects along path, text={PROPERTY OF KNUTH}, text effects/.cd, text along path, fit text to path, characters={font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries, text=Silver!50!white},}, yscale=-1,]
  \path [cm={{0.48287,0,0,1.8349,(-16.198,-1039.1)}} , opacity=0.8, even odd rule, inner color=gray, outer color=gray!5] (736.09,693.71)arc(-0.309:180.309:342.99 and 7.831)arc(-180.309:0.309:342.99 and 7.831) -- cycle;
  \path [cm={{0.85307,0,0,0.37556,(-183.43,-23.731)}}, opacity=0.8, even odd rule, inner color=gray!5, outer color=gray!75] (535.62,684.32)arc(-0.529:180.529:93.969 and 14.095)arc(-180.529:0.529:93.969 and 14.095) -- cycle;
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.4335,0.38566,-0.38566,1.4335,(-33.152,-10.038)}}]
    \path [draw=darkgray] (116.6100,36.2740) .. controls (106.7100,36.4130) and (96.8790,39.3390) .. (88.7700,45.3680) .. controls (72.9270,57.1480) and (65.0760,76.3500) .. (67.7080,95.8680) .. controls (68.4440,101.3200) and (72.0540,106.2500) .. (72.7700,111.5200) .. controls (77.8610,116.4100) and (81.1820,122.5000) .. (87.0520,126.7400) .. controls (104.3300,139.2400) and (129.0100,140.5600) .. (146.8600,128.2400) .. controls (151.8500,124.8100) and (155.9800,120.5600) .. (159.5500,115.6800) .. controls (161.9400,112.4200) and (164.0000,107.7900) .. (168.2100,106.5200) .. controls (171.8500,105.4300) and (174.6000,109.4300) .. (178.2400,108.8700) .. controls (180.8900,108.4600) and (180.2600,105.1500) .. (182.4900,104.1800) .. controls (183.7600,103.6300) and (191.4300,101.0400) .. (192.4000,101.3100) .. controls (194.3000,101.8300) and (194.9800,104.2500) .. (197.2400,104.0900) .. controls (200.2200,103.8800) and (201.1700,100.1700) .. (203.8300,99.5240) .. controls (206.2300,98.9440) and (207.9600,102.3500) .. (209.6800,103.4600) .. controls (213.6300,106.0000) and (217.3800,102.4400) .. (219.1500,99.0870) .. controls (221.9400,100.5400) and (223.6000,104.5100) .. (226.8600,104.7700) .. controls (229.9500,105.0300) and (231.9200,101.5000) .. (234.5200,101.8100) .. controls (238.7000,102.2900) and (241.3600,106.2400) .. (246.4000,104.7100) .. controls (252.3200,102.9100) and (257.6700,95.1210) .. (262.4600,91.3060) .. controls (264.3200,89.8210) and (267.1800,88.0660) .. (267.4900,85.4620) .. controls (267.8300,82.6080) and (264.0500,78.5600) .. (262.2100,76.6490) .. controls (258.8100,73.1240) and (250.3600,74.7740) .. (245.8300,74.7740) .. controls (230.7900,74.7740) and (215.8100,73.5880) .. (200.8000,73.5870) .. controls (194.7000,73.5860) and (181.9300,76.5800) .. (181.8300,68.2740) -- (171.1500,67.8370) -- (162.8600,64.1180) .. controls (161.5600,56.8790) and (154.3800,50.4020) .. (148.6800,46.2740) .. controls (139.5100,39.6370) and (128.0100,36.1150) .. (116.6100,36.2740) -- cycle(92.7390,73.7120) .. controls (106.2200,73.3810) and (109.5500,94.1550) .. (95.1770,96.8680) .. controls (80.3360,99.6700) and (75.4960,76.5540) .. (90.6770,73.9310) .. controls (91.3870,73.8080) and (92.0760,73.7280) .. (92.7390,73.7120) -- cycle;
    \path [fill=gray, opacity=0.8, draw=gray!10!Silver] (116.6700,36.4410) .. controls (106.7700,36.5800) and (96.9330,39.5060) .. (88.8240,45.5350) .. controls (72.9810,57.3150) and (65.1300,72.5160) .. (67.7620,92.0350) .. controls (68.4980,97.4890) and (72.1080,102.4200) .. (72.8240,107.6900) .. controls (77.9150,112.5700) and (81.2360,118.6600) .. (87.1050,122.9100) .. controls (104.3800,135.4100) and (125.0600,136.7300) .. (142.9200,124.4100) .. controls (147.9000,120.9700) and (152.0400,116.7200) .. (155.6100,111.8500) .. controls (157.9900,108.5900) and (164.0500,105.9600) .. (168.2600,104.6900) .. controls (171.9000,103.6000) and (174.6500,107.6000) .. (178.2900,107.0300) .. controls (180.9400,106.6200) and (180.3100,103.3200) .. (182.5400,102.3500) .. controls (183.8100,101.7900) and (191.4900,99.2080) .. (192.4500,99.4720) .. controls (194.3500,99.9960) and (195.0300,102.4100) .. (197.2900,102.2500) .. controls (200.2700,102.0400) and (201.2200,98.3360) .. (203.8900,97.6910) .. controls (206.2800,97.1110) and (208.0100,100.5200) .. (209.7300,101.6300) .. controls (213.6800,104.1700) and (217.4300,100.6100) .. (219.2000,97.2540) .. controls (221.9900,98.7100) and (223.6500,102.6700) .. (226.9200,102.9400) .. controls (230.0000,103.1900) and (231.9700,99.6700) .. (234.5700,99.9720) .. controls (238.7500,100.4600) and (241.4200,104.4100) .. (246.4500,102.8800) .. controls (252.3800,101.0700) and (253.7300,95.2880) .. (258.5100,91.4720) .. controls (260.3700,89.9880) and (263.2300,88.2330) .. (263.5400,85.6290) .. controls (263.8900,82.7740) and (260.1000,78.7270) .. (258.2600,76.8160) .. controls (254.8700,73.2910) and (246.4200,74.9410) .. (241.8900,74.9410) .. controls (226.8400,74.9410) and (211.8700,73.7550) .. (196.8600,73.7540) .. controls (190.7600,73.7530) and (177.9900,76.7470) .. (177.8900,68.4410) -- (167.2000,68.0040) -- (158.9200,64.2850) .. controls (157.6100,57.0460) and (150.4300,50.5690) .. (144.7300,46.4410) .. controls (135.5600,39.8040) and (128.0700,36.2810) .. (116.6700,36.4410) -- cycle(92.7930,73.8790) .. controls (106.2700,73.5480) and (109.6000,94.3220) .. (95.2300,97.0350) .. controls (80.3900,99.8370) and (75.5500,76.7210) .. (90.7300,74.0970) .. controls (91.4410,73.9750) and (92.1300,73.8950) .. (92.7930,73.8790) -- cycle;
    \path [draw=gray, inner color=Silver, outer color=gray] (116.6100,35.9030) .. controls (106.7100,36.0420) and (96.8790,38.9680) .. (88.7700,44.9970) .. controls (72.9270,56.7770) and (65.0760,75.9780) .. (67.7080,95.4970) .. controls (68.4440,100.9500) and (72.0540,105.8800) .. (72.7700,111.1500) .. controls (77.8610,116.0300) and (81.1820,122.1300) .. (87.0520,126.3700) .. controls (104.3300,138.8700) and (129.0100,140.1900) .. (146.8600,127.8700) .. controls (151.8500,124.4400) and (155.9800,120.1800) .. (159.5500,115.3100) .. controls (161.9400,112.0500) and (164.0000,107.4200) .. (168.2100,106.1500) .. controls (171.8500,105.0600) and (174.6000,109.0600) .. (178.2400,108.5000) .. controls (180.8900,108.0900) and (180.2600,104.7800) .. (182.4900,103.8100) .. controls (183.7600,103.2600) and (191.4300,100.6700) .. (192.4000,100.9300) .. controls (194.3000,101.4600) and (194.9800,103.8800) .. (197.2400,103.7200) .. controls (200.2200,103.5000) and (201.1700,99.7980) .. (203.8300,99.1530) .. controls (206.2300,98.5730) and (207.9600,101.9800) .. (209.6800,103.0900) .. controls (213.6300,105.6300) and (217.3800,102.0700) .. (219.1500,98.7160) .. controls (221.9400,100.1700) and (223.6000,104.1400) .. (226.8600,104.4000) .. controls (229.9500,104.6500) and (231.9200,101.1300) .. (234.5200,101.4300) .. controls (238.7000,101.9200) and (241.3600,105.8700) .. (246.4000,104.3400) .. controls (252.3200,102.5400) and (257.6700,94.7500) .. (262.4600,90.9340) .. controls (264.3200,89.4500) and (267.1800,87.6950) .. (267.4900,85.0910) .. controls (267.8300,82.2360) and (264.0500,78.1890) .. (262.2100,76.2780) .. controls (258.8100,72.7530) and (250.3600,74.4030) .. (245.8300,74.4030) .. controls (230.7900,74.4030) and (215.8100,73.2170) .. (200.8000,73.2160) .. controls (194.7000,73.2150) and (181.9300,76.2090) .. (181.8300,67.9030) -- (171.1500,67.4660) -- (162.8600,63.7470) .. controls (161.5600,56.5080) and (154.3800,50.0310) .. (148.6800,45.9030) .. controls (139.5100,39.2660) and (128.0100,35.7440) .. (116.6100,35.9030) -- cycle(92.7390,73.3410) .. controls (106.2200,73.0100) and (109.5500,93.7840) .. (95.1770,96.4970) .. controls (80.3360,99.2990) and (75.4960,76.1830) .. (90.6770,73.5590) .. controls (91.3870,73.4370) and (92.0760,73.3570) .. (92.7390,73.3410) -- cycle;
    \path [opacity=0.7, left color=gray!15!Silver, right color=gray!30!darkgray] (167.4700,106.5200) .. controls (171.1000,105.4300) and (173.8600,109.4300) .. (177.5000,108.8700) .. controls (180.1500,108.4600) and (179.5100,105.1500) .. (181.7500,104.1800) .. controls (183.0200,103.6300) and (190.6900,101.0400) .. (191.6500,101.3100) .. controls (193.5600,101.8300) and (194.2400,104.2500) .. (196.5000,104.0900) .. controls (199.4800,103.8800) and (200.4300,100.1700) .. (203.0900,99.5240) .. controls (205.4900,98.9440) and (207.2100,102.3500) .. (208.9300,103.4600) .. controls (212.8800,106.0000) and (216.6400,102.4400) .. (218.4000,99.0870) .. controls (221.1900,100.5400) and (222.8600,104.5100) .. (226.1200,104.7700) .. controls (229.2000,105.0300) and (231.1800,101.5000) .. (233.7800,101.8100) .. controls (237.9500,102.2900) and (240.6200,106.2400) .. (245.6500,104.7100) .. controls (251.5800,102.9100) and (256.9300,95.1210) .. (261.7200,91.3060) .. controls (263.5800,89.8210) and (266.4300,88.0660) .. (266.7500,85.4620) .. controls (267.0900,82.6080) and (263.3100,78.5600) .. (261.4700,76.6490) .. controls (258.0700,73.1240) and (249.6200,74.7740) .. (245.0900,74.7740) .. controls (230.0400,74.7740) and (215.0700,73.5880) .. (200.0600,73.5870) .. controls (193.9600,73.5860) and (181.1900,76.5800) .. (181.0900,68.2740) -- (172.2600,68.5790) .. controls (172.2600,68.5790) and (166.2900,62.9150) .. (160.8600,66.8740) .. controls (139.4300,82.5150) and (165.3600,107.1600) .. (167.4700,106.5200) -- cycle;
    \path [even odd rule, left color=gray!50!white, right color=white] (181.8800,78.3750) -- (174.6900,79.6560) -- (178.5300,84.5000) -- (266.28,84.5) -- (266.6600,83.5310) -- (262.6600,78.3750) -- (181.8800,78.3750) -- cycle(180.1600,86.5310) -- (181.88,88.688) -- (264.6600,88.6880) -- (265.5000,86.5310) -- (180.1600,86.5310) -- cycle;
    \path [opacity=0.5, even odd rule, fill=Silver!25!white] (181.88,78.308) -- (174.67,79.589) -- (178.52,84.433) -- (266.6,84.4330) -- (266.9800,83.4640) -- (262.9600,78.3080) -- (181.8800,78.3080) -- cycle(180.15,86.464) -- (181.88,88.6200) -- (264.9700,88.6200) -- (265.8200,86.4640) -- (180.1500,86.4640) -- cycle;
    \path [shift={(-2.37,-0.14812)},opacity=0.6,even odd rule, fill=Silver] (183.5000,102.9800)arc(-0.941:180.941:4.450600 and 5.649)arc(-180.941:0.941:4.450600 and 5.649) -- cycle;
    \path [cm={{1,0,0,0.75089,(18.101,21.947)}},opacity=0.6,even odd rule, fill=Silver] (183.5000,102.9800)arc(-0.941:180.941:4.450600 and 5.649)arc(-180.941:0.941:4.450600 and 5.649) -- cycle;
    \path [cm={{1.0998,0,0,0.68534,(15.481,29.365)}},opacity=0.6,even odd rule, fill=Silver] (183.5000,102.9800)arc(-0.941:180.941:4.450600 and 5.649)arc(-180.941:0.941:4.450600 and 5.649) -- cycle;
    \path [cm={{1,0,0,0.79022,(48.023,18.712)}},opacity=0.600,even odd rule, fill=Silver] (183.5000,102.9800)arc(-0.941:180.941:4.450600 and 5.649)arc(-180.941:0.941:4.450600 and 5.649) -- cycle;
    \path [cm={{0,1,-1.1967,0,(367.27,-78.817)}},opacity=0.6,even odd rule, fill=Silver] (183.5000,102.9800)arc(-0.941:180.941:4.450600 and 5.649)arc(-180.941:0.941:4.450600 and 5.649) -- cycle;
    \path [cm={{1.6841,0,0,1.3147,(-42.707,-50.996)}},opacity=0.7,even odd rule, fill=white] (183.5000,102.9800)arc(-0.941:180.941:4.450600 and 5.649)arc(-180.941:0.941:4.450600 and 5.649) -- cycle;
    \path [fill=Silver!5!white] (117.0000,38.0310) .. controls (114.9400,38.0620) and (112.8500,38.2330) .. (110.7800,38.4690) .. controls (103.6500,39.2810) and (96.5470,42.3430) .. (90.6250,46.3120) .. controls (85.0700,50.0360) and (81.0570,54.7760) .. (77.4380,60.3440) .. controls (66.5840,77.0430) and (66.9810,99.2500) .. (78.9060,115.4100) .. controls (93.6200,135.3400) and (125.5200,141.5100) .. (145.6900,126.1200) .. controls (152.8100,120.6900) and (160.2900,113.6200) .. (164.1200,105.3800) .. controls (157.4100,108.8600) and (153.7000,116.9300) .. (148.1200,121.9400) .. controls (137.8500,131.1600) and (122.3600,134.4300) .. (109.0000,131.8800) .. controls (103.0800,130.7400) and (97.5730,128.2100) .. (92.4380,125.1200) .. controls (55.3020,102.8500) and (71.5560,44.3380) .. (113.1600,40.3120) .. controls (126.1800,39.0520) and (138.9600,42.7790) .. (148.7200,51.5620) .. controls (154.2100,56.5090) and (158.7000,66.5630) .. (166.4100,68.0310) .. controls (160.8100,63.9260) and (158.0400,57.6670) .. (153.3400,52.6880) .. controls (148.1000,47.1310) and (141.5100,43.6620) .. (134.5000,40.9690) .. controls (128.8300,38.7910) and (122.9400,37.9430) .. (117.0000,38.0310) -- cycle(97.5620,74.0000) .. controls (106.6100,78.1170) and (107.3700,93.8210) .. (95.0000,96.1560) .. controls (88.1710,97.4460) and (83.4350,93.2550) .. (81.8120,88.0940) .. controls (83.0940,94.1620) and (88.2520,99.4810) .. (95.9690,98.0000) .. controls (109.4100,95.4210) and (108.0500,77.5650) .. (97.5620,74.0000) -- cycle;
    \begin{scope}
      \path (92,88) ++(-90:15) coordinate (a);
      \clip (a)  arc (-90:0:15) |- (current bounding box.south east) -- (current bounding box.north east) -| cycle;
      \path [cm={{1.5874,0.57246,-0.31593,0.87607,(-74.579,-70.635)}}, opacity=0.7, even odd rule, inner color=white, outer color=Silver] (158.79,65.549) arc (0:180:20.11 and 27.442) arc (-180:0:20.11 and 27.442) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  []
  \path
    [
    postaction={decorate},
      preaction={%
        decorate,
        decoration={%
          text effects/.cd, characters/.append={xshift=1, yshift=1, scale=1.05, opacity=.5, text=gray},
        },
      }
    ] (100,160) ++(120:60) arc (120:-90:60);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Variant 2 (Shiny)

Here's a shinier version based on a much-mangled adaption of [Mark Wibrow's 3D stacked disks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175415/)

```
\pdfminorversion=7
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out,% tudalen 344
  inner color=transparent!0,
  outer color=transparent!85]
\tikzset{%
  blob/.style={opacity=0.8, path fading=fade out, even odd rule, inner color=white!50!Silver, outer color=Silver},
}
\usepackage{cabin}
\begin{document}
% basic key based on Inkscape export from Timothy King's key at https://openclipart.org/detail/211/shiny-key
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.8pt, x=0.8pt, decoration={text effects along path, text={PROPERTY OF KNUTH}, text effects/.cd, text along path, fit text to path, characters={font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries, text=Silver!50!white},}, yscale=-1,]
  \coordinate (c) at (103,158.5);
  \path [cm={{0.48287,0,0,1.8349,(-16.198,-1039.1)}} , opacity=0.8, even odd rule, inner color=gray, outer color=gray!5] (736.09,693.71)arc(-0.309:180.309:342.99 and 7.831)arc(-180.309:0.309:342.99 and 7.831) -- cycle;
  \path [cm={{0.85307,0,0,0.37556,(-183.43,-23.731)}}, opacity=0.8, even odd rule, inner color=gray!5, outer color=gray!75] (535.62,684.32)arc(-0.529:180.529:93.969 and 14.095)arc(-180.529:0.529:93.969 and 14.095) -- cycle;
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.4335,0.38566,-0.38566,1.4335,(-33.152,-10.038)}}]
    \path [draw=darkgray] (116.61,36.274) .. controls (106.71,36.413) and (96.879,39.339) .. (88.77,45.368) .. controls (72.927,57.148) and (65.076,76.35) .. (67.708,95.868) .. controls (68.444,101.32) and (72.054,106.25) .. (72.77,111.52) .. controls (77.861,116.41) and (81.182,122.5) .. (87.052,126.74) .. controls (104.33,139.24) and (129.01,140.56) .. (146.86,128.24) .. controls (151.85,124.81) and (155.98,120.56) .. (159.55,115.68) .. controls (161.94,112.42) and (164,107.79) .. (168.21,106.52) .. controls (171.85,105.43) and (174.6,109.43) .. (178.24,108.87) .. controls (180.89,108.46) and (180.26,105.15) .. (182.49,104.18) .. controls (183.76,103.63) and (191.43,101.04) .. (192.4,101.31) .. controls (194.3,101.83) and (194.98,104.25) .. (197.24,104.09) .. controls (200.22,103.88) and (201.17,100.17) .. (203.83,99.524) .. controls (206.23,98.944) and (207.96,102.35) .. (209.68,103.46) .. controls (213.63,106) and (217.38,102.44) .. (219.15,99.087) .. controls (221.94,100.54) and (223.6,104.51) .. (226.86,104.77) .. controls (229.95,105.03) and (231.92,101.5) .. (234.52,101.81) .. controls (238.7,102.29) and (241.36,106.24) .. (246.4,104.71) .. controls (252.32,102.91) and (257.67,95.121) .. (262.46,91.306) .. controls (264.32,89.821) and (267.18,88.066) .. (267.49,85.462) .. controls (267.83,82.608) and (264.05,78.56) .. (262.21,76.649) .. controls (258.81,73.124) and (250.36,74.774) .. (245.83,74.774) .. controls (230.79,74.774) and (215.81,73.588) .. (200.8,73.587) .. controls (194.7,73.586) and (181.93,76.58) .. (181.83,68.274) -- (171.15,67.837) -- (162.86,64.118) .. controls (161.56,56.879) and (154.38,50.402) .. (148.68,46.274) .. controls (139.51,39.637) and (128.01,36.115) .. (116.61,36.274) -- cycle(92.739,73.712) .. controls (106.22,73.381) and (109.55,94.155) .. (95.177,96.868) .. controls (80.336,99.67) and (75.496,76.554) .. (90.677,73.931) .. controls (91.387,73.808) and (92.076,73.728) .. (92.739,73.712) -- cycle;
    \path [fill=gray, opacity=0.8, draw=gray!10!Silver] (116.67,36.441) .. controls (106.77,36.58) and (96.933,39.506) .. (88.824,45.535) .. controls (72.981,57.315) and (65.13,72.516) .. (67.762,92.035) .. controls (68.498,97.489) and (72.108,102.42) .. (72.824,107.69) .. controls (77.915,112.57) and (81.236,118.66) .. (87.105,122.91) .. controls (104.38,135.41) and (125.06,136.73) .. (142.92,124.41) .. controls (147.9,120.97) and (152.04,116.72) .. (155.61,111.85) .. controls (157.99,108.59) and (164.05,105.96) .. (168.26,104.69) .. controls (171.9,103.6) and (174.65,107.6) .. (178.29,107.03) .. controls (180.94,106.62) and (180.31,103.32) .. (182.54,102.35) .. controls (183.81,101.79) and (191.49,99.208) .. (192.45,99.472) .. controls (194.35,99.996) and (195.03,102.41) .. (197.29,102.25) .. controls (200.27,102.04) and (201.22,98.336) .. (203.89,97.691) .. controls (206.28,97.111) and (208.01,100.52) .. (209.73,101.63) .. controls (213.68,104.17) and (217.43,100.61) .. (219.2,97.254) .. controls (221.99,98.71) and (223.65,102.67) .. (226.92,102.94) .. controls (230,103.19) and (231.97,99.67) .. (234.57,99.972) .. controls (238.75,100.46) and (241.42,104.41) .. (246.45,102.88) .. controls (252.38,101.07) and (253.73,95.288) .. (258.51,91.472) .. controls (260.37,89.988) and (263.23,88.233) .. (263.54,85.629) .. controls (263.89,82.774) and (260.1,78.727) .. (258.26,76.816) .. controls (254.87,73.291) and (246.42,74.941) .. (241.89,74.941) .. controls (226.84,74.941) and (211.87,73.755) .. (196.86,73.754) .. controls (190.76,73.753) and (177.99,76.747) .. (177.89,68.441) -- (167.2,68.004) -- (158.92,64.285) .. controls (157.61,57.046) and (150.43,50.569) .. (144.73,46.441) .. controls (135.56,39.804) and (128.07,36.281) .. (116.67,36.441) -- cycle(92.793,73.879) .. controls (106.27,73.548) and (109.6,94.322) .. (95.23,97.035) .. controls (80.39,99.837) and (75.55,76.721) .. (90.73,74.097) .. controls (91.441,73.975) and (92.13,73.895) .. (92.793,73.879) -- cycle;
    \path [draw=gray, inner color=Silver, outer color=gray] (116.61,35.903) .. controls (106.71,36.042) and (96.879,38.968) .. (88.77,44.997) .. controls (72.927,56.777) and (65.076,75.978) .. (67.708,95.497) .. controls (68.444,100.95) and (72.054,105.88) .. (72.77,111.15) .. controls (77.861,116.03) and (81.182,122.13) .. (87.052,126.37) .. controls (104.33,138.87) and (129.01,140.19) .. (146.86,127.87) .. controls (151.85,124.44) and (155.98,120.18) .. (159.55,115.31) .. controls (161.94,112.05) and (164,107.42) .. (168.21,106.15) .. controls (171.85,105.06) and (174.6,109.06) .. (178.24,108.5) .. controls (180.89,108.09) and (180.26,104.78) .. (182.49,103.81) .. controls (183.76,103.26) and (191.43,100.67) .. (192.4,100.93) .. controls (194.3,101.46) and (194.98,103.88) .. (197.24,103.72) .. controls (200.22,103.5) and (201.17,99.798) .. (203.83,99.153) .. controls (206.23,98.573) and (207.96,101.98) .. (209.68,103.09) .. controls (213.63,105.63) and (217.38,102.07) .. (219.15,98.716) .. controls (221.94,100.17) and (223.6,104.14) .. (226.86,104.4) .. controls (229.95,104.65) and (231.92,101.13) .. (234.52,101.43) .. controls (238.7,101.92) and (241.36,105.87) .. (246.4,104.34) .. controls (252.32,102.54) and (257.67,94.75) .. (262.46,90.934) .. controls (264.32,89.45) and (267.18,87.695) .. (267.49,85.091) .. controls (267.83,82.236) and (264.05,78.189) .. (262.21,76.278) .. controls (258.81,72.753) and (250.36,74.403) .. (245.83,74.403) .. controls (230.79,74.403) and (215.81,73.217) .. (200.8,73.216) .. controls (194.7,73.215) and (181.93,76.209) .. (181.83,67.903) -- (171.15,67.466) -- (162.86,63.747) .. controls (161.56,56.508) and (154.38,50.031) .. (148.68,45.903) .. controls (139.51,39.266) and (128.01,35.744) .. (116.61,35.903) -- cycle(92.739,73.341) .. controls (106.22,73.01) and (109.55,93.784) .. (95.177,96.497) .. controls (80.336,99.299) and (75.496,76.183) .. (90.677,73.559) .. controls (91.387,73.437) and (92.076,73.357) .. (92.739,73.341) -- cycle;
    \path [opacity=0.7, left color=gray!15!Silver, right color=gray!30!darkgray] (167.47,106.52) .. controls (171.1,105.43) and (173.86,109.43) .. (177.5,108.87) .. controls (180.15,108.46) and (179.51,105.15) .. (181.75,104.18) .. controls (183.02,103.63) and (190.69,101.04) .. (191.65,101.31) .. controls (193.56,101.83) and (194.24,104.25) .. (196.5,104.09) .. controls (199.48,103.88) and (200.43,100.17) .. (203.09,99.524) .. controls (205.49,98.944) and (207.21,102.35) .. (208.93,103.46) .. controls (212.88,106) and (216.64,102.44) .. (218.4,99.087) .. controls (221.19,100.54) and (222.86,104.51) .. (226.12,104.77) .. controls (229.2,105.03) and (231.18,101.5) .. (233.78,101.81) .. controls (237.95,102.29) and (240.62,106.24) .. (245.65,104.71) .. controls (251.58,102.91) and (256.93,95.121) .. (261.72,91.306) .. controls (263.58,89.821) and (266.43,88.066) .. (266.75,85.462) .. controls (267.09,82.608) and (263.31,78.56) .. (261.47,76.649) .. controls (258.07,73.124) and (249.62,74.774) .. (245.09,74.774) .. controls (230.04,74.774) and (215.07,73.588) .. (200.06,73.587) .. controls (193.96,73.586) and (181.19,76.58) .. (181.09,68.274) -- (172.26,68.579) .. controls (172.26,68.579) and (166.29,62.915) .. (160.86,66.874) .. controls (139.43,82.515) and (165.36,107.16) .. (167.47,106.52) -- cycle;
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (116.61,35.903) .. controls (106.71,36.042) and (96.879,38.968) .. (88.77,44.997) .. controls (72.927,56.777) and (65.076,75.978) .. (67.708,95.497) .. controls (68.444,100.95) and (72.054,105.88) .. (72.77,111.15) .. controls (77.861,116.03) and (81.182,122.13) .. (87.052,126.37) .. controls (104.33,138.87) and (129.01,140.19) .. (146.86,127.87) .. controls (151.85,124.44) and (155.98,120.18) .. (159.55,115.31) .. controls (161.94,112.05) and (164,107.42) .. (168.21,106.15) .. controls (171.85,105.06) and (174.6,109.06) .. (178.24,108.5) .. controls (180.89,108.09) and (180.26,104.78) .. (182.49,103.81) .. controls (183.76,103.26) and (191.43,100.67) .. (192.4,100.93) .. controls (194.3,101.46) and (194.98,103.88) .. (197.24,103.72) .. controls (200.22,103.5) and (201.17,99.798) .. (203.83,99.153) .. controls (206.23,98.573) and (207.96,101.98) .. (209.68,103.09) .. controls (213.63,105.63) and (217.38,102.07) .. (219.15,98.716) .. controls (221.94,100.17) and (223.6,104.14) .. (226.86,104.4) .. controls (229.95,104.65) and (231.92,101.13) .. (234.52,101.43) .. controls (238.7,101.92) and (241.36,105.87) .. (246.4,104.34) .. controls (252.32,102.54) and (257.67,94.75) .. (262.46,90.934) .. controls (264.32,89.45) and (267.18,87.695) .. (267.49,85.091) .. controls (267.83,82.236) and (264.05,78.189) .. (262.21,76.278) .. controls (258.81,72.753) and (250.36,74.403) .. (245.83,74.403) .. controls (230.79,74.403) and (215.81,73.217) .. (200.8,73.216) .. controls (194.7,73.215) and (181.93,76.209) .. (181.83,67.903) -- (171.15,67.466) -- (162.86,63.747) .. controls (161.56,56.508) and (154.38,50.031) .. (148.68,45.903) .. controls (139.51,39.266) and (128.01,35.744) .. (116.61,35.903) -- cycle(92.739,73.341) .. controls (106.22,73.01) and (109.55,93.784) .. (95.177,96.497) .. controls (80.336,99.299) and (75.496,76.183) .. (90.677,73.559) .. controls (91.387,73.437) and (92.076,73.357) .. (92.739,73.341) -- cycle;
      % modified, mangled and simplified from Mark Wibrow's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175415/
      \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
        \path [left color=black!50, right color=black!50, middle color=black!25] (c) (c) circle (150);
        \path [bottom color=black!25, top color=white, fill opacity=.25] (c) circle (150);
        \foreach \r in {75,165,255,345}
          \foreach \i in {0,2,...,15}
            \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] (c) -- ++(\r+15-\i:150) arc (\r+30-\i:\r-15+\i:150)  -- cycle;
        \path [bottom color=black!25, top color=white] (c) circle (47.5);
     \end{scope}
     \path [fill=Silver!5!white] (117,38.031) .. controls (114.94,38.062) and (112.85,38.233) .. (110.78,38.469) .. controls (103.65,39.281) and (96.547,42.343) .. (90.625,46.312) .. controls (85.07,50.036) and (81.057,54.776) .. (77.438,60.344) .. controls (66.584,77.043) and (66.981,99.25) .. (78.906,115.41) .. controls (93.62,135.34) and (125.52,141.51) .. (145.69,126.12) .. controls (152.81,120.69) and (160.29,113.62) .. (164.12,105.38) .. controls (157.41,108.86) and (153.7,116.93) .. (148.12,121.94) .. controls (137.85,131.16) and (122.36,134.43) .. (109,131.88) .. controls (103.08,130.74) and (97.573,128.21) .. (92.438,125.12) .. controls (55.302,102.85) and (71.556,44.338) .. (113.16,40.312) .. controls (126.18,39.052) and (138.96,42.779) .. (148.72,51.562) .. controls (154.21,56.509) and (158.7,66.563) .. (166.41,68.031) .. controls (160.81,63.926) and (158.04,57.667) .. (153.34,52.688) .. controls (148.1,47.131) and (141.51,43.662) .. (134.5,40.969) .. controls (128.83,38.791) and (122.94,37.943) .. (117,38.031) -- cycle(97.562,74) .. controls (106.61,78.117) and (107.37,93.821) .. (95,96.156) .. controls (88.171,97.446) and (83.435,93.255) .. (81.812,88.094) .. controls (83.094,94.162) and (88.252,99.481) .. (95.969,98) .. controls (109.41,95.421) and (108.05,77.565) .. (97.562,74) -- cycle;
      \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
        \foreach \r in {45,135,225,315}
          \foreach \i in {0,2,...,30}
            \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] (c) -- ++(\r+30-\i:65) arc (\r+30-\i:\r-30+\i:65)  -- cycle;
      \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
    \path [opacity=0.3, even odd rule, fill=Silver!25!white] (181.88,78.308) -- (174.67,79.589) -- (178.52,84.433) -- (266.6,84.433) -- (266.98,83.464) -- (262.96,78.308) -- (181.88,78.308) -- cycle (180.15,86.464) -- (181.88,88.62) -- (264.97,88.62) -- (265.82,86.464) -- (180.15,86.464) -- cycle;
    \path [even odd rule, opacity=.5, right color=white, left color=white, middle color=gray!50!white] (181.88,78.375) -- (174.69,79.656) -- (178.53,84.5) -- (266.28,84.5) -- (266.66,83.531) -- (262.66,78.375) -- (181.88,78.375) -- cycle (180.16,86.531) -- (181.88,88.688) -- (264.66,88.688) -- (265.5,86.531) -- (180.16,86.531) -- cycle;
    \path [shift={(-2.37,-0.14812)}, blob] (183.5,102.98)arc(-0.941:180.941:4.450600 and 5.649)arc(-180.941:0.941:4.450600 and 5.649) -- cycle;
    \path [cm={{1,0,0,0.75089,(18.101,21.947)}}, blob] (183.5,102.98)arc(-0.941:180.941:4.450600 and 5.649)arc(-180.941:0.941:4.450600 and 5.649) -- cycle;
    \path [cm={{1.0998,0,0,0.68534,(15.481,29.365)}}, blob] (183.5,102.98)arc(-0.941:180.941:4.450600 and 5.649)arc(-180.941:0.941:4.450600 and 5.649) -- cycle;
    \path [cm={{1,0,0,0.79022,(48.023,18.712)}}, blob] (183.5,102.98)arc(-0.941:180.941:4.450600 and 5.649)arc(-180.941:0.941:4.450600 and 5.649) -- cycle;
    \path [cm={{0,1,-1.1967,0,(367.27,-78.817)}}, blob] (183.5,102.98)arc(-0.941:180.941:4.450600 and 5.649)arc(-180.941:0.941:4.450600 and 5.649) -- cycle;
    \path [cm={{1.6841,0,0,1.3147,(-42.707,-50.996)}}, blob, fill=white] (183.5,102.98) arc(-0.941:180.941:4.4506 and 5.649) arc(-180.941:0.941:4.4506 and 5.649) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \path
    [
    postaction={decorate},
      preaction={%
        decorate,
        decoration={%
          text effects/.cd, characters/.append={xshift=1, yshift=1, scale=1.05, opacity=.5, text=gray},
        },
      }
    ] (c) ++(120:60) arc (120:-90:60);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Variant 3 (Power of Knuth)

The code for the third variant causes the answer to exceed the length limit. While one donkey answer may be considered a misfortune and two explained by mere carelessness, a third would surely constitute deliberate trespass beyond the bounds of propriety. Hence, [here is the source code in question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30113217#30113217).

Comment: Oh god. Don-Key. It took me some time to understand this. ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Terrible, isn't it? But I could not resist ....

Comment: What's worse is that 9 people liked it enough to up-vote it!

Comment: @cfr Much better than I'd imagined.

Comment: you can practically hear the children squealing: OMG, how cute is this, aww, I want one...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried to make a somewhat shinier version, though it still doesn't look right.

Comment: I needed to read the inscription to get it. I associated a bump key with `Don-Key` ... (-.(-.-).-)

Comment: @Suuuehgi What's a 'bump key'? Of course the inscription is crucial: otherwise it could be a frog-key or a Suuuehgi-key or, really, anybody's key ....

Comment: @cfr A [specially crafted](http://lmgtfy.com/?s=d&q=bump+key) [key](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hr23tpWX8lM) with which one can open any lock fast and easily. I understood _Don_ in a mafia sense. ;-)

Comment: Can you please update the source code  of the _Power of Knuth_? The link is broken.

Comment: @user156344 The link works for me and the code there still compiles with current Texlive 2019. ?

Answer (score 104):

In response to a suggestion by the OP in chat, I am pleased to announce the availability of a provisional logo for the TeX Society for the Protection of Donkeys (TSPD).

[image: TSPD]

The donkey itself is an adaptation of an [openclipart.org](https://openclipart.org/) [donkey by frankes](https://openclipart.org/detail/214238/donkey-coloured). The original SVG was opened in Inkscape and exported to TikZ code. This code was then partially cleaned and modified. A simple key-value interface was added to configure the donkey's colouring.

The donkey code became `asyn.tex`. This was compiled to PDF using pdfLaTeX.

[image: donkey]

`asyn.pdf` was then used to create the logo using TikZ code based on that I used to create the [TSPCD circular logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5tPD.png) [posted in chat a couple of days ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29968902#29968902).

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage{textcomp,microtype}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\TeXT{%
  T\kern -.1667em}
\newcommand*\TeXe{%
  \lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125em}
\newcommand*\TeXX{%
  X\spacefactor 1000}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i/\j/\k in {Purple4/Purple4/45mm,Purple1/Purple4/35mm} \path [inner color=\i, outer color=\j, draw=Purple4, line width=1.5pt, double distance=.75mm, double=Purple1] circle (\k);
  \path [decorate, decoration={text effects along path, text={\TeXT\TeXe\TeXX \textbullet{} SOCIETY \textbullet{} FOR \textbullet{} THE \textbullet{} PROTECTION \textbullet{} OF \textbullet{} DONKEYS \textbullet{}\ }, text effects/.cd, text along path, fit text to path, characters={font=\LARGE, text=Silver}}] (90:38mm) arc (90:-270:38mm);
  \node {\includegraphics[height=50mm] {asyn}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The PDF compiled by pdfLaTeX was finally converted to PNG using ImageMagick's `convert` utility.

```
convert -density 300 <filename>.pdf -quality 100 tspd.png
```

Since TSPCD and TSPD have very similar acronyms, it is essential to bear in mind that

[image: duck \neq donkey]

or, in code,

```
$x \neq y \forall x \in \{\text{donkeys}\}, y \in \{\text{ducks}\}$
```

[image: TSPCD; duck; donkey; TSPD]

## *Caveat emptor ...*

## Appendix

The code for the duck is the duckastic work of the site's resident duck, Paulo Cereda, posted in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63732/cute-child-friendly-document-in-latex/63759#63759).

The system will not allow me to post the source `asyn.tex` which contains the code for the donkey here, even in a dedicated answer and even if I remove all permissible spaces and do some further compacting codewise. But I have found a solution allowing me to post [the donkey source code](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30010020#30010020) used to create `asyn.pdf`.

Code for inequality:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (hwyaden)  {\includegraphics{duck}};
  \node (n) [right=of hwyaden, font=\Huge, scale=10] {$\neq$};
  \node [right=of n] {\includegraphics{asyn}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Code for duck-donkey series:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tspcd}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{duck}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{asyn}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tspd}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Pretty draw and code. First time I see a donkey with green eyes... lol

Comment: Hmm, this donkey looks strikingly similar to mine...

Comment: @Robert I tried to copy the antlers as faithfully as I could ;).

Comment: You forgot to escape the braces in your statement of the inequality. `$x \neq y \forall x \in \{\text{donkeys}\}, y \in \{\text{ducks}\}$`

Comment: @Sigur Oddly enough, the eye colour is, I think, the only colour I didn't change. (Well, also the pupil of the eye, but that pretty much has to be black.)

Comment: (1) How would you center \TEX on top of circle? (2) How would you make the space on left and right of  \TEX appear equal?

Comment: @Maesumi Well you could run the text from, say, 85 to 265 or whatever rather than 90 to 270. Is that what you mean?

Comment: In many circular logos there are two parts. Each part is centered. The bottom part reads left to right as in [this example](http://www.ranklogos.com/fashion-brands-logos/sportswear-logos/converse-logo/). I was trying to use your code for that effect.

Comment: @Maesumi You just need to start and end at the appropriate angles. If you want 2 parts for your logo, of course you will need 2 paths - one in each direction. However, TikZ is not ideal for that case.

Comment: Some examples of what I was looking for are [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75638/recreating-a-logo-text-around-a-circle).

Comment: @Maesumi Yes ... ?? It isn't difficult. You just specify the angles appropriately, as I said before.

Answer (score 98):

This is my randomized TeX donkey contribution, made with `Tikz`.
The idea is the emerging of the letters of "Esel" from the central TeX following an Archimedes spiral.

[image: randomized TeX donkey]

The letters are chosen randomly and have random size and rotation.
An advantage of this approach is that the silhouette of the donkey has not to be very perfect.
I like this kind of design as a logo because it is immediately recognisable, but every time that it is compiled (with at least 1 min difference), the output is slightly different because it has a random component.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\donkey{
    (0.8,-4.5)--(1.5,-4.5)
    ..controls(1.3,-3.5)..(1.75,-1.5)
    ..controls(2.3,-0.5)..(2.5,0.5)
    ..controls(3,1.8)..(3.75,1.25)
    ..controls(4.5,0.7)and(5.3,1.2)..(4.3,2.4)
    ..controls(3.9,2.8)..(3.8,3.75)
    ..controls(3.5,5.6)..(3.35,3.75)
    ..controls(3.2,3)..(3.05,3.75)
    ..controls(2.7,5.5)..(2.6,3.75)--(2.6,3.1)
    ..controls(2.2,2.9)..(1,2)
    ..controls(-0.5,1.3)..(-2.2,1.7)
    ..controls(-3.3,1.8)and(-4.4,1.3)..(-4.8,0.25)
    ..controls(-5,-0.5)..(-5,-1.4)
    ..controls(-5,-3.5)..(-4.6,-1.4)
    ..controls(-4.5,0)..(-4.3,-1.3)
    ..controls(-4,-1.8)..(-4,-4.5)--(-3.4,-4.5)
    ..controls(-3.2,-0.7)..(-2,-1.2)
    ..controls(-0.5,-1.5)..(0.8,-1.2)--cycle
   }

\pgfkeys{/donkey/letter/.is choice}
\pgfkeys{/donkey/letter/1/.code=\def\letter{E}}
\pgfkeys{/donkey/letter/2/.code=\def\letter{s}}
\pgfkeys{/donkey/letter/3/.code=\def\letter{e}}
\pgfkeys{/donkey/letter/4/.code=\def\letter{l}}

\pgfkeys{/donkey/font size/.is choice}
\pgfkeys{/donkey/font size/1/.code=\def\size{\huge}}
\pgfkeys{/donkey/font size/2/.code=\def\size{\Large}}
\pgfkeys{/donkey/font size/3/.code=\def\size{\normalsize}}
\pgfkeys{/donkey/font size/4/.code=\def\size{\footnotesize}}
\pgfkeys{/donkey/font size/5/.code=\def\size{\tiny}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip[rounded corners,scale=1.3] \donkey;
  \foreach \angle in {1700,1722,...,16000}{
      \pgfmathparse{int(rnd*4+1)}\xdef\letterchoice{\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathparse{int(rnd*4+1)}\xdef\sizechoice{\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathparse{rnd*360}     \xdef\rotation{\pgfmathresult}
    \node[/donkey/.cd,letter=\letterchoice,font size=\sizechoice,
          /tikz/.cd,font=\size,rotate=\rotation] 
        at (\angle:\angle/1720){\letter};}
  \node at (0,0){\huge\TeX};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Thank you very much! And sorry. Initially the letters from “Esel” where extracted with your `stringstrings` package. A very useful package indeed!

Comment: Thanks for the plug.  But I am the first to admit (OK, the 2nd) that `stringstrings` is as slow as a snail.  It was my first package, when I really had no clue about what I was doing.  But occasionally, it can still shine.

Comment: @cfr: Thank you. I only saw it the day after I received the newsletter. However, I am very happy to have had so many votes; really did not expect that :D. Now I hope that it will inspire somebody for something more useful.

Comment: I know. I feel guilty now for posting *two* answers. I'm astonished that a bad pun is now my most popular answer!

Comment: that's so rad! can i ask if it is possible to make the randomized donkey scalable (right now we need n statements for n letters). something like putting letters in an array and using them from there? i would love to create some graphics like the one in child of books (http://www.readingisourthing.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/IMG_8886.jpg)

Answer (score 57):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\unitlength}{0.00083333in}
\usepackage{epic}
\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(4974,3714)(0,-10)
\drawline(2037,1362)(1962,12)(2112,1362)
\drawline(1887,2412)(4437,2412)(4437,1437)
    (1887,1437)(837,2262)(462,1812)
    (12,2187)(687,3012)(837,3687)
    (837,3087)(1812,2412)
\drawline(1887,1437)(1512,12)(1962,1437)
\put(687,2637){\circle{150}}
\drawline(4362,1437)(4287,162)(4287,1437)
\drawline(4137,1437)(3987,162)(3987,1437)
\drawline(4437,2412)(4962,1587)
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I almost mistook this for a photo.

Comment: @cfr this is indeed a photograph taken with an experimental HiTeX camera which outputs photos in TeX or LaTeX depending on the format selected. Other formats are under development.

Comment: what really puzzles me is why you use the `epic` package instead of the `legendary`?

Comment: Yes, yes, YES! `:)`

Comment: Congrats for the bounty! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda :-)

Comment: @PauloCereda: This is how he stays ahead of me...!

Answer (score 44):

I posted the following artworks in the chatroom, and I was kindly asked to posted them here as well. I am also marking this answer as community wiki since there is no need to harvest these juicy reputation points. `:)`

The first artwork is an attempt of reproducing the official project logo as a vector image. I drew it by hand and made some conversions in order to obtain the corresponding `.tex` code, available [in this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/cereda/3e8ee6e279c0fd783419fdb3d0b6258a) due to code length limitations in our site. The result is as follows:

[image: Quack]

The second artwork was made as a recurring joke in the chatroom, as we are fond of ducks. What if a duck wants to win the contest and goes into the competition disguised as a donkey? Then we came up with the following drawing, with the corresponding `.tex` code available [in this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/cereda/16288d775f24758d58e898e0b35d15cb) for the very same reasons stated above:

[image: Quack]

Although the disguise is almost perfect, some smart bloke might argue there is no yellow donkey available in nature. Then we are now inclined to provide a improved version of the duck's disguise, as seen in the following image (`.tex` code provided [in this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/cereda/be0f7cd73a4b235f3ea2d92570c2f56d)):

[image: Quack]

The final improvement would be making the duck wear green contact lens, so the donkey disguise would be technically perfect. Maybe in the upcoming future. `:)`

Comment: Bendigedig! Though I would prefer you to be getting the juiciness of the points ;).

Comment: @cfr: ooh I could use the juiceness for bounties! `:)`

Comment: some even smarter bloke might point out that donkeys are not blue either

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but the point is to fool the competition organisers in order to enter and they evidently believe a blue one to be paradigmatic.

Answer (score 35):

In the package `linearb`, there is a Linear B ideogram called `\BPhorse`, which is clearly not a donkey, but a horse and looks like this:

[image: A Linear B horse]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{linearb}
\begin{document}
\textlinb{\BPhorse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently, I am too late for the party.

Comment: There is always time! `:)`

Comment: And you can also [win a duck](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6652)!

Answer (score 28):

It's my donkey named... Lenny.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\savestack\eye{\rotatebox{90}{$^\circ\kern-2.5pt%
  \raisebox{1pt}{\smash{\scalebox{1}[.6]{\raisebox{3pt}{)}}}\kern.2pt%
  \scalebox{1.7}[1]{\scalebox{.5}[1.1]{$\smash{\vert}$}\kern-1.5pt$>$}}$}}
\savestack\nose{\raisebox{0pt}{\scalebox{.7}{..}}}
\savestack\mouth{\scalebox{1.00}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{(}}}
\scalebox{.97}[2]{\mbox{\textbackslash}}\kern-1.8pt\stackanchor[10pt]{\eye \eye}{%
  \stackon[1pt]{\mouth}{\nose}\,}\kern-3.5pt\scalebox{1.18}[2]{/}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It reminds of the [Mari Lwyd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mari_Lwyd), although that's a horse, of course.

Comment: Course, you couldn't really call her 'Lenny' in that case ....

Comment: @cfr Oh my.  That bad, huh?

Comment: ;) Not at all. The Mari Lwyd is quite popular - in theory, if not in practice. Bit grim, maybe, but surely no worse than Halloween and probably rather less so. Something about the nostrils and the white, though .... I find this one a bit creepy. And the eye sockets ....

Comment: ooh this donkey looks very naughty, I like it! `:)`

Comment: I like it. Has Lenny a meaning? I found a book called "Lenny, the lost donkey". (The ears looks a bit like the logo of Cologne - a rival city to mine (at least for the soccer fans).)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Lenny is making reference to another facial figure constructed of glyphs (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308600/how-to-include-a-lenny-face-in-a-latex-document-e-g-%cd%a1-%cd%9c%ca%96-%cd%a1).  You will note that this face is based very much on my answer there.

Answer (score 18):

## A dounckey*

*to use the name @mickep gave this creature :)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\definecolor{skin}{RGB}{161,140,126}
\definecolor{bill}{RGB}{238,212,191}
\definecolor{hair}{RGB}{89,72,72}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[body=skin,bill=bill,shorthair=hair]
    \node[skin,rotate=45,scale=3] at (1.7,1.55) {\textsf{s}};
    \fill[hair,rotate=45] (2.4,0.13) ellipse (0.15 and 0.07);
    \begin{scope}[yshift=1]
        \clip (0.3,2.2) circle (0.4);
    \fill[skin] (0.9,2.3) circle (0.4);
  \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=1]
        \clip (0.3,2.2) circle (0.35);
    \fill[bill] (0.9,2.3) circle (0.35);
  \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (1.5,2.05) circle (0.4);
    \fill[skin] (1.0,2.35) circle (0.4);
  \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (1.5,2.05) circle (0.35);
    \fill[bill] (1.0,2.35) circle (0.35);
  \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Well well, what to say, I was meandering through the list of answers and found no `ascii` contributions `;-)`. Hence, for the sake of (my own) satisfaction,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,listings,graphicx,varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{filecontents,listings,graphicx,varwidth}

\begin{filecontents*}{donkey.txt}
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWMMMMMMMMMMMWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXddXMMMMMMMMM0oOWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNd'cKMMMMWWMMKc;OWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWOcokXMMMMMMWKl:kNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXod0KNMMMMMNkloOXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWxo0KKWMMWN0ooOKXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWklkK0KNWXOxccOKXNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOlokxk00Ooc:cxKXNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOolddokko:;:lx0KWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXOdcoookxl;:cok0KNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNXK0xoc:oodxc,::cx0KNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXOolollc;oxdoclccoOKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNXXXKkdollddolldkdooodkKNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWXKkoccc::coooxdllddocccloxOXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWN0Odoc:;,;:loooloddoodl::cc::lldOKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWX0xl::;;;:lodddolclollool:::c:::clodkKNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWXOxoc;,,:coxxdlllcccloollllcc:::::::loookXWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNKkdolcccclxkxxdollcccccooolcc:::;;::::clodox0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNKko::;;;cxOkkdoolcc:ccccloolc:;;;,,;:lloxxdoddd0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNKkdl:;,,:ldxxddollcc::ccclloolc:;;:c::::ccokkkxdodKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWN0dlc::ldxxkxddollollc::ccllloolccccldxo:,,',:okkdooxXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNKOdc:;cdOOkddddolloooc::::clloddolcc::coxkkkO0kxkkolllxKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWNXKKKKXXXNNNWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0dlclodxxddooodoolooolc:;;:clodddolc:;;:ccodkOOOkkxolllcd0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWX0OxdoolcccllooooddxxkkkOOOO000KKXXXNNNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXxlooddxddolooooooooolc:;;;;:oxxxdol:,,;,,;:cldddddolclllloOXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNKOxolllllllc::::cccccc::cccccccccccclllooodxxkkO0KXXXNNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWNXXK00OOOkkkOOOkkdolooooollcclllllloollc:;;,,:oOOkdoc;,,,',,,;:cloooollllllookKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNKOdoloooooooollccccccccccc:::::::::::::::c:::::::ccccllloodxxkkOOOO0000OOOOkkxxddoollcc:cccccllllcccclllllcc::ccllccllc:;;,,,;lkOkxoc:;,''''',,,:cllllllooodxk0XWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXOxoooooooooooollccccccccccllc::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::ccc::ccccccccccccccccllllllcc:cc::::ccc::::cccccccccc:::ccccc::;,,,,,;okkxoc::;,,''',;;;::cllloodxO0XNNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKOxdddooooooollllllccccccccccc:ccc::::::::::::::::::::::;:::::::cccc::ccccccccccclllllllllllllccccccc:::::::::::ccccccccccc:;,,,''',:lxxoc::;,,,'''',:llllllodk0XXNXNNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWN0kddddddooooolllllllccccccccccc::ccc:ccc::::::::::::::::::::cccc:::clccccccccc:ccccllllllllllllllccccccc:::;:::::;::cccccc:::;;,,,'',,,,:ddlc;;,'''....,;cllodxk0XXXNNNNNNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMN0xdooodddddooolllccclcccccclllllc:;::::ccccc:::::cccc:::::::::::cc::::cccc::::::cccccccccccccclloolllcccc::::;;;:::;;::::::::;;;;,,,,,,,''',cxkdl;'......';:cloxO0KKKXXKKKKKKNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOddooooddddddooollcccccccccclloolcc::;;:c:ccc::::cccc::::c:::::::::c::cccccc:::ccccccccccccccclclooolllllc::;:::;;;:;;;;:::;;;;;;;;;,,'''...,oXWWNKOl;'...'';:ldOKKKKKK0kkkxxx0NMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOdoodddddddddooollllcccccllllcllollc:::::cccccccccccc::::::::ccc:::cc::ccccc::::::cccccccccccccccllolllllllc::;;;;;;;;;;:::::;:::;;;,,''....'dNWWMMMMWXOdc,'',:lxOKK0K0Okkd,,ccxNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0dooldxddddoooooooollllccllllllllllllccccc::cccc::::::::::::::ccc:cccc:c::::::::::::::::cccccccccccllllllolccc::;;;:;;;;;:::::::::;;,'''...';kNMMMMMMMMMMMWKkdodxkOKOkkOkddl..,cxNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNkolcd0kxddddddooooollllllllllllllccllllcc:::::c::::::::cccc::ccc::::ccccc:::::::::::::::cccccccccccccccllllcc::::;;;;::;;;:ccllc:;;,'''...'c0WWWMMMMMMMMMMWMMMMMWWNXOocodolc:,'c0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXdlclKNOxdooddddoddooooooooollllllcccloolc:::ccc::::::ccccc:::ccccc:::c:cc::cc::::::::ccccclccccccccccccclllcc::::;;;;:::;;:cclll:;,,''...;xXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXOl,,:::;,:ONMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMKdl:xWW0xxdoddoodddooooooollllllllccclloolcccccccccc::::::::::cccccc::ccc:::ccc::::::cccccccccccccccccccllllccc::::;;;;:c:;::cllc:;,'''',l0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXkoodxxOXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMKdc:kWWXkxxdddddddoolllllolllcllllcccllooolccc:::ccc:cc:::cccccc:cccccccc::cc:ccc::::cccccccccccccccclllllllllccc:::;;;:cc:::cll:;,'',,ckNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXxc;xWMWKkxxddddddollccloollllllllccllllllllcc:::::::ccccccc:::::cccccccccccc::::::::::::::::ccccccclllloollllllllllc:::ccc::ccc:,,,;cxXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWOc,lKMMWXkddddxxdollclloollllllllllllllcllllcc::::;:cccccccccccccccccccccc:::::::::::::::::::cccccccccllollooolooollcccccccccc:;;;lkKWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXd;;dNMMMN0xdxxxddolllloolllllllllllooocccllllc:::;;:cccc:::ccccccccc:::cc:::::::::::::::::::cclllcccccloooddoooollllc:::ccc:::cld0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0l,,xNMMMWXkxxxddooolooollllllloollloolcccllllcc:::::ccc:::ccc::::cc:::::::::::;;;;;;;::::cccccccccccclooooooooolcllcc:::ccccclkXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNk:''xWMMMMXOxxddoooooooooolllloooolooolc::cccllccc::::::::::::::::c:::::::::;;;;;;;;;;:::ccccc:::::ccloooodoolllccccccc::clloONMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKl,.;KMMMMWXkxxdddoddooooooolloddoodxxdl:::;:ccccllcc:::::::::::::::::::::::;;;;;;;;;;:::cccc:::c::clloooooooollllcccc:::lldONMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk;.;0MMMMMWKkkxdooooooooooollooddxk0K0koc:;;::::cclccc:::::::::::;;;;;;;;;;;;;::;;;;;:::ccccccclcclllllllooooollllc::::coxONMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNxlOWMMMMMMNOkkxdoolllllooooloodxk0XNNXK0kocc:;::::ccc::::::::::::::;;;;:::::::::::::::clllooooooolllllllloooolccc::cclxkOKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWMMMMMMMMWKOkxxdoollllloooooodkKXNNWWNNXK0kdocc::cccccclc:;;::c::ccccccccclloooolllooodxxxkOOkxdolllllllloolc;,;:coxO00XWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXKOxxddoollllllooodk0XNWMMMWNNNXXX0OkxdoloooooolccllooodxxdxxxkkOO0000OOOOOO0KKKKXKkdolccclcclllc::::codkOOKNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNX0xdddoollllcloodk0XNWMMMMMMMWNXXXXXXKK0OOkkkOOOOOOO00KKKKXXXXNNNNNNNNXXK00KXXXNNKklc::;;::::::::codxkO00XWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNXXKkdddoolllllodxk0KNMMMMMMMMMMMWNXXXXXNNNNNXXXXXXXXXNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNXXXXXKKKKKKXXX0xc::;;;;:::::cldkOOKNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNXXNX0dolllllllodxk0KNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNXKXXXXXXNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNXXXXKKKKKKKKXXNNNNNNXOl::;;::::ccllxO0KXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWK0XNN0dolllllloodk0XNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWNXKKKKKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKKK000KKKKXXNWWWWMMMMMMMXkdlcccccllood0XXXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0O0XXXOdooooooodxO0KNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWNXXXKKKKKKK0000OOO00KXNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKkdollllllodOXXXNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0xOKKX0xddoddddxkO0KNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWWWNNNNNNNNWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNKOkxdllllloOKXXXNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWOdx0KK0xlloodddxkkk0NWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNKOkxolcllok0KX0KWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWOodO000kocloooodxxxkXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKOxdlcc:coxO000OXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOook0O0koccloooooddkXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOoccc:cccdk00OxOWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKdldkOOOkoc:cooddoddxKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKdccclcccldO0OxxKMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0ccddxxkkdc::cooooodxKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWOoolllllclxOOkodXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0ooxxxxxocc::cloooox0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNkoolollcldkkdocxWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXxoxkkxl:cccccloodx0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKdollooccdxxolllOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOdxkxo:;,;:ccllodONMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKxlcllllcloooc:coKMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0doddlc;;;:cllloxKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXxc:c::c:oxdol:;,oXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0dlloodoc::cclloONMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXd::::;;:xKkdl:;:kWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0dllodOKdcc:cc:l0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWkc:::::l0NOddc:dXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMKollodONOlcccc:lKMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWOc::ccoONXkxxc:kWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMKoclolxXXo:ccc:lKMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWOc:ccckNMXxxdc:kWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXdloocdXWkllcc::xNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNkc:::lKWMKdddllOWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNxlolcoKMXdccc:;c0WWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNkc::;dNMMKdddll0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNxodlcoKMW0lcc::;dNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKxc:;;kWMW0ddoco0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMKololld0WMNkll:;;cOWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOc:::c0MMWOcllcckWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWOll::coOWMMKocc;;:dXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXo,;::oXMMM0c;:;;l0WMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWkc:;;cckNMMWk::;;:l0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMO;.,;;dXMMMW0oc;;;ldkKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMKl::cccldONMKl;,;:coKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMO;''';oKMMMMMWO:;;,',o0XNNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0olc;,;,,oXXd:;:;:co0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWOc,;:l0WWMMMWx'.'',cloodxxkKNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNXd'.'.,:odoccccc::ldkONMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNx;:clkNWWMMXd;;cllclllodkKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNo'..,:cccc:cloc,,;,',dNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0;''',dNMMMWWNKK0OOO00KNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOoooolodxOKXXOc'''';lxOOO0KNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMKc..';:lk0KXXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWNNNWWMMMMK:.,;:lllooood0WMMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk,,;:looloddd0NWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWMMMMMMMMMWKOkxdddxkO0KNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWKOkxddddxkO0XWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
\end{filecontents*}
\newsavebox{\asciiart}
\newcommand{\donkey}{\raisebox{.8\height}{\resizebox{1.5ex}{!}{\usebox{\asciiart}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\asciiart}
\begin{varwidth}{\maxdimen}
\noindent\lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{donkey.txt}
\end{varwidth}
\end{lrbox}%

 \scalebox{50}{\donkey{}}

\end{document}
```

to get a nice beautiful donkey:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Fashionably late code golf version of [this fellow.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/70/Eeyore.gif)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
E$\lor$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's too late: I had to look at the URL to get this :(. Please don't use `minimal` for examples, though.

Comment: Just a little confused, how does that look like a donkey?

Comment: It is just a symbolic representation of the name of a donkey well-known in children's literature. Or, it's just a bad pun. Whichever.

Comment: You have to ping @hola for the comment to be seen.